# Installing Tesseract for android

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

Can someone guide me through the process of installing Tesseract OCR engine to use with Eclipse for android development. I have tried a few tutorials but they always lose me at some point. the last thing I tried was trying to download the repository for Tesseract available on github but when following the instructions (after having downloaded the NDK) and following this commands in the command line

```
`git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
cd tess
cd tess-two
ndk-build***
android update project --path .
ant release`
```

when I get to `ndk-build` it doesnt recognize it as a command. also I have no idea what `ant release` is or does or if I need to install some software to use it.

Comment: Its not clear what platform you are on. Assuming you set `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` as G3M stated... On Windows, run `"%ANDROID_NDK_ROOT%\ndk-build"`. On Linux and OS X, run `$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/ndk-build`. You can literately use the environmental variable because it will be substituted by the shell.

Comment: In addition to setting `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`, you should also set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. Internally, all the tools use them.

Answer (score 1):

Add the ndk folder to your PATH variable. If you are on windows, add the ndk-build path(../android-ndk-r10) to your environment variable PATH. If you are using MAC or linux set/export  your PATH variable to include the path to your ndk folder.
Also set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to point to the ndk folder. This will resolve the ndk-build command not recognized issue.

ant release - is to build your android project for release. This will building your final apk file that goes into play store.

ant debug - is to build the debug build of your application.

Set the JAVA_HOME variable to point to the JDK installation folder for ant to work properly.

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Progra~1\Java\<jdkdir>
```

Comment: I did: 
C:\Users\>set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=C:\Users\eriel\Documents\Android\android-ndk-r10
but still gives the error "'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Also, now I know what is ant for but, do I have to install something to get access to its commands or they are available to the cmd line by default?